# Cannot import telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Had telethon working with my code.
For some reason, my code did not work anymore after some time, so tried to upgrade telethon library. Now, even not able to import telethon.

Followed installation instructions here: https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic/installation.html

```
# pip3 show telethon

Name: Telethon
Version: 1.8.0
Summary: Full-featured Telegram client library for Python 3
Home-page: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon
Author: Lonami Exo
Author-email: totufals@hotmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/XXX/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requires: pyaes, rsa
Required-by:
```

After this, trying to do basic import of telethon library fails.
Running python 3.5.2

```
# python3 -c "import telethon;"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client.telegramclient import TelegramClient
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/client/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .users import UserMethods  # Required for everything
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .. import errors, utils, hints
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/telethon/hints.py", line 56, in <module>
    typing.BinaryIO
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 1077, in __subclasscheck__
    if super().__subclasscheck__(cls):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/abc.py", line 225, in __subclasscheck__
    for scls in cls.__subclasses__():
TypeError: descriptor '__subclasses__' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the python version you're using (see https://github.com/python/typing/issues/266); and it's also an open issue in Telethon repo (see https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1177).

Upgrade your python to the latest version and the problem will go away.

Comment: thanks, this solved the issue. Tried to search for solution before posting, but did not find the 2 issues you mentionned. Thanks a lot.